# Lambda to monitor multi region AWS changes/events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently I am using Lambda to autotag/start/stop my instances. But I find that that appear to be region specific. Do I need to deploy it on every region if I want to do the same thing on every region? Is there a better way?

Even then some regions don't have lambda?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a lambda in every region. You just need to change the region in your service config object which can be set like this:

```
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({region: 'eu-west-1'});
```

OR

```
AWS.config.update({region:'eu-west-1'});
```

You'll need to use an array consisting of all the regions you need to monitor, iterate through them, set the AWS configuration to the target region and then perform your operations. Just make sure to set the region in configuration before you autotag/start/stop your instances so that the operations would be performed in your desired region.

Comment: This will be useful if I want my lambda to access another region's resource, but what about the triggers. I currently use cloudwatch events, can I configure it to check all regions? Looks like theres no option for that?

Comment: @JiewMeng I am not sure what your exact requirement is but the cloudwatch event triggers and targets are region specific. Events cannot check all regions. However, you can use an SNS topic as target and handle those events. The topic could have a service(http/https endpoint that processes the events) as a subscriber. Another option is to use SQS. You'll have to replicate this in every region though.

Comment: Where is this service config placed? Do you speak about Boto3 or what?